# How to update column values in the table?

Tags: java

- What is the problem in this code? where it is update the all column values with the same last one .

  ```
  public class  dbconnection {
  java.sql.Connection con;
  java.sql.Statement st;
  ResultSet rs;
  public   EncBean getConnection()throws SQLException{
  EncBean encBean1 = new EncBean(); 
  String v_url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.138:1522:orcl2";
  String v_username= "scott";
  String v_password = "tiger";

      try
      {
  DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(v_url,v_username,v_password); 
  System.out.println ("Connection to Oracle database  was Established");
      }


  catch ( SQLException e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return encBean1;
  }

  public   EncBean selectRows()

  {
   EncBean encBean2 = new EncBean(); 
  try
      {

      String SQLselect="select JOB_NAME from job";
      st=con.createStatement();
      rs=st.executeQuery(SQLselect);

  while (rs.next()) {

      encBean2.setName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
                  }   

      }
   catch ( Exception ex ) 
  {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return encBean2;
  }


  public  void updateRows(String updatedname){

  try
  {
  Statement stmt =   con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

  ResultSet srs = stmt.executeQuery("select job_name from job " );

    while (srs.next()) {

    srs.updateString("job_name", updatedname);
    srs.updateRow();
    con.commit();} 
    System.out.println("An existing user was updated successfully!");}
    catch(SQLException err){
    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }}}
  ```

  This is the main

  ```
  public class mainenc {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   dbconnection dbcon = new dbconnection();
   EncBean encbeancon=    dbcon.getConnection();
   EncBean encBean5 = dbcon.selectRows(); 
   enc concatinputs = new enc();  
   EncBean encBeanconcat = concatinputs.funconcat(encBean5.getName());
   EncBean encBean4 =    concatinputs.inputencryption(encBeanconcat.getConcatenatedData());
   String vReserverbin= encBean4.getReversedBinary();
   String  ascistring=  concatinputs.convertBinaryStringToString(vReserverbin);
    dbcon.updateRows(ascistring); 
      }}
  ```

  What is the problem in this code? where it is update the all column values with the same last one .

Comment: First problem: your indentation is crazy.

Comment: Second Problem: You naming convention is crazy.

Answer (score 0):

After updated method you should write list method again.

Comment: plz can you do it for me?

Comment: I'll describe birefly.You connect database and list your record.After that updated them.No problem so far.Now you should again list method.maybe write  getConnection() end of update method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take this example:

```
 UPDATE tableB
 SET tableB.value , tableA.value, tableB.value)
 WHERE tableA.name = 'Joe'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of obvious: `dbcon.updateRows(...)` calls for the update method and that method does the job.

But as Erhan said, you don't get to see the result because you don't actually make use of updated records, e.g. show them etc. At least, you can check it out at the DB level if op is completed.

But I really disliked your comment:

> plz can you do it for me?

You should do your own task and ask help when you need a hand. But never expect someone else to do your job mate.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i tried more then i request from him to do it